# Indentation in nested list

Tags: python

Can anybody please explain how the value of level is working for indenting the list items.

I have the code written. But is it that the value of level is getting incremented each time fn() is being called recursively? How does the value of level become 0 when it comes back to the item '8' in the outer list?

```
m=[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]], 8]
def fn(item,level):
    for each_item in item:
        if isinstance(each_item,list):
            fn(each_item,level+1)
        else:
            for tabspace in range(level):
                print("\t",end='')
            print(each_item)
```

The output of the code is:

```
1
2
3
    4
    5
        6
        7
8
```

Comment: _"But is it that the value of level is getting incremented each time fn() is being called recursively?"_ Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Some changes you could make to your function:

- Give a default value of 0 to `level`, then you don't have to specify the value when you call the function
- You can repeat strings like this `'\t' * 3`, which results in `\t\t\t`

Something like this:

```
def fn(items, level=0):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            fn(item, level + 1)
        else:
            indentation = '\t' * level
            print('%s%s' % (indentation, item))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works fine. But can you just refer my code and tell me how the value of level gets decremented to 0 while printing 8 in the outer list.

Comment: Each call of `fn()` has its own `level`, and the function never increase the value of `level` for itself, it only passes `level + 1` to the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

You ask "how the value of level gets decremented to 0 while printing 8 in the outer list", and the answer is : it isn't. Plain simply.

Each call (recursive or not, it doesn't matter) of a function creates a `frame` instance in the interpreter stack. This `frame` holds the per-function-call local variables values (in your example the values for `items` and `level`.

So the first call creates a frame with `items=[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]], 8]` and `level=0` (assuming you used a default value as suggested by Paco H. or passed it manually). The for loop starts, and when it reaches the fourth item `[4, 5, [6, 7]]`, the function calls itself back. This creates a new `frame` on the stack with `items=[4, 5, [6, 7]]` and `level=1`. This frame is totally independant from the caller function's frame - the `items` and `level` in the first frame stay what they were - and start executing the function's code.

Then it reaches the third element of `[4, 5, [6, 7]]` which is a list and recurse , thus creating a third frame on the stack with `items=[6, 7]` and `level=2`. This third call doesn't recurse, and when it finishes (reaches the end of the for loop) the interpreter pops the top frame from the stack and give controls back to the previous one (the one with `items=[4, 5, [6, 7]]` and `level=1`). This one finishes it's loop too and terminates so the interpreter pops it and resume execution of the first frame, where `level` is *still* `0`. It is not "decremented" because it has never been incremented at all ;)

Comment: That helped. Thank you so much Sir.